# Wordpress IP restriction w/ Header Location Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site I'm trying to lock down to a set of IPs. I'm using the following code as the first thing in index.php: (IPs obfuscated here)

```
$matchedIP = 0;
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$validIPs = array("x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x");

foreach($validIPs as $validIP)
{
    if($IP == $validIP)
    {
        $matchedIP = 1;
    }
}

if($matchedIP == 0)
{
    header('Location: http://google.com.au');
}
```

The IP check works fine, as assorted assertions can confirm. What doesn't work is the redirect, which never happens. The full index.php is as below:

```
<?php

$matchedIP = 0;
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$validIPs = array("x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x");

foreach($validIPs as $validIP)
{
    if($IP == $validIP)
    {
        $matchedIP = 1;
    }
}

if($matchedIP == 0)
{
    header('Location: http://google.com.au');
}

/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');

//require('./phpinfo.php');
```

The curious thing is, when commenting out the wordpress blog-header require and including a require to a simple phpinfo page instead, the redirect behaves as expected.

Am I misunderstanding the way PHP's processing works in some way? Surely it should hit the redirect before it even considers loading any required files below?

EDIT: Windows IIS7 backend, PHP Version 5.2.17, Wordpress Version 3.4.2

Comment: Try adding an `exit(0);` after the `header` directive. Edit: btw you can remove the `foreach`-loop by using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: Thanks! That totally worked! You should submit it as an answer so I can mark it as answered. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a proper redirect, you have to terminate the script execution after the `header`-directive:

```
if(!in_array($IP, $validIPs))
{
    header('Location: http://google.com.au');
    exit(0);
}
```

The reason is, that if you let Wordpress continue its execution, it will send a HTTP status code `200` and the browser will ignore the `Location` header. Only a sub-set of the HTTP status codes make use of the `Location` header.

With the `exit` in place, PHP stops executing and will automatically send a `302` HTTP status, which tells the browser to redirect to the URL specified in the `Location` header.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop for it

```
<?php

$matchedIP = 0;
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$validIPs = array("x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x", "x.x.x.x");

if(in_array($IP, $validIPs))
{
    header('Location: http://google.com.au');
    exit(0);
}

?>
```